# My blog hosted in distant server is still connecting to localhost

Tags: localhost, shared-hosting

my website was installed and fixed on localhost, then i hosted it on a distant server, i also chaged the parameters in the `wp-config.php` file to meet to distant database.
However, when i try to call it in the url tab, i see always the localhost call in the bottom of the browser. This is my url [website](http://www.patisserie-orient.fr/zconsulting/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your content is linked to your localhost install. I would suggest using a plugin like [Search & Replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) to amend your URLs. Also if you haven't already, you will need to change the two entries in the wp_options table (where wp_ is the prefix used). They are rows 0 & 37. These are your URLs for moving your site.

The next time you move your site from local to a live site check out the [WordPress guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), it's got lots of handy tips and solutions to problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

You must change URLs in the database: Use these queries in phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.olddomain.com/blog/','http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.olddomain.com/blog/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/blog/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');
```

And check to see if any URLs are hardcoced in theme files. See [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and [How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location  »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're *au fait* with using PHPMyAdmin, or whichever MySQL web-interface you've been using, my recommendation would be to do the following;

1. Export your entire database in SQL format
2. Open the SQL file in a program like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (any syntax-highlighter will do but this is my preference)
3. Press **CTRL+H** to open the "Find & Replace" dialogue box.
4. In "Find", enter "localhost"
5. In "Replace", type "www.patisserie-orient.fr/zconsulting"
6. Hit "Replace All in Current Document"
7. Save the SQL file AS a different name (ensuring a back-up of your old file)
8. Drop your entire database (**only if you're 100% sure you have a copy!**)
9. Import the new SQL file

You should now have a fully up-to-date database using your new URL.

This method is especially effective if you use a number of plugins as I've found they often store absolute URLs in the `wp_options` table.

Comment: Using find/replace with a text editor in a text dump doesn't work; it breaks serialzed data.

Comment: Ah, of course. How would you go about changing such details for plugins using serialized data then?

Comment: Use queries in phpmyadmin for that plugins options table

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? I don't understand how that will help with serialized data. Does MySQL have code to serialize data?